# how add incremented counter to each element of a list

Tags: scala

I have:

```
scala> val alphaList = List("a", "b")
alphaList: List[java.lang.String] = List(a, b)
```

and I'd like a list of tuples like:

```
List((a,1),(b,2))
```

Normally in Java I'd do something like:

```
List alphaList = new ArrayList<String>()
alphaList.add("a");alphaList.add("b");
List newList = new ArrayList<String>();
for ( int i = 0; ii < alphaList.size(); i++ )
  newList.add(alphaList[i] + i);
```

What I'm trying to get at, is how do I get an incrementing variable that I can use while processing a List?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
alphaList.zipWithIndex.map {
  case (k, v) => (k, v + 1)
}
```

The `zipWithIndex` replaces each element with a tuple of itself and its index (starting from 0). The `map` matches the tuple, and creates a new tuple with the index incremented by 1, so that you start from 1, instead of 0.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to Axel22's answer, which is fine :

```
alphaList.zip(Stream.from(1))
```

Comment: Would be better, though, if `Iterator.from(1)` compiled.

Comment: Indeed that is what I tried to do first, don't see why that should not be available on Iterator.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `Iterable`. I think `from` should be available on `Iterable`, and that is the one I was looking for. I do not like using `Iterator` directly very much.

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
def zipWithIndex1[A](xs:Seq[A]) = xs.map{var i = 0; x => i+=1; (x,i)}
```

Test:

```
zipWithIndex1("sdlfkjsdlf")
//--> Vector((s,1), (d,2), (l,3), (f,4), (k,5), (j,6), (s,7), (d,8), (l,9), (f,10))
```

Comment: This depends on map implementation: does it process Seq elements in order. I don't think it is required to do so

Comment: I think that this should be ensured for sequences... But, very interesting solution... I didn't know that everything after the `x =>` becomes a closure, even without adding braces.

Comment: I don't see why it should. Scala collection implementation is very regular, and as long as map is not redefined it will work that way, but I don't think implementations are precluded to do otherwise should it be more efficient. Of course it will not work with a ParSeq, but I aggree a ParSeq is not a Seq

Comment: @didierd: you're probably right, but I can't find this explicitly stated in the docs anywhere.